# How to get the previous monday in SAS (previous monday in week)?

Tags: sas

I am completely new to SAS, and I'm editing someone else's code.

I have code similar to this:

```
data tablename1;
set schema.tablename; 
if date_column > '08may2017'd;
run;
```

Instead of a hard coded date (08may2017) I need the date for the previous Monday.
How I would do this in SAS?

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Determing-dates-of-previous-Monday-and-Sunday/td-p/193229?nobounce

Answer (score 2):

The `intnx` function is your answer:

```
   data tablename1;
   set schema.tablename;
   if date_column > intnx('week1.2',date(),-1,'B');
   run;
```

For more info about the `intnx` function, see [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212700.htm)